# 9px difference in JQuery coordinates?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have [this site](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/)

I wanted to calculate the width of each element on the screen (left and right and content) using *jQuery* but the total is not equal with screen width.

**jQuery CODE:**

```
var windowsize = $(window).outerWidth();
console.log('screen width:',windowsize);

var stanga= jQuery('#secondary').outerWidth();
console.log('left width:',stanga);

var dreapta= jQuery('.right').outerWidth();
console.log('width right:',dreapta);

var content= jQuery('#main-content').outerWidth();
console.log('width content',content);

var suma=stanga+dreapta+content;
console.log('total:',suma);
```

I put an image to better show the difference.

http://i59.tinypic.com/281d4eh.jpg

There is a difference of 9px that I don't understand.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe the scrollbar?

Comment: i don`t know...maybe :)

Comment: Just to test what @LarsW has mentioned, try adding `*{overflow: hidden;}` this will break some things no doubt but have another look at the widths then. It should remove the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you re-size your screen, I bet the number of `px` that you are off changes.
reason why, you have absolute values mixed with relative values, and since you are not using `width: calc()` for your `#main-content` which is currently set to `width: 48%;` your screen elements will not total `100%`. what I would recomend, is to set your  `#main-content` with too 100% minus the width of the right and left img's. something like this:

```
#main-content{width: calc(100% - 820px)}
```